# Rearrange Columns and Rows from a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have one CSV file that contains the columns Movie_ID, and Movie_Name and another that contains the columns User_ID, Movie_ID, and Rating.  How can I make a new dataframe where the columns are Movie_Name or Movie_ID and the rows are User_ID and Rating?  For instance something like

| User_ID | Movie1 | Movie2 | Movie3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | 5 |

NOTE: not every user has rated every movie.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For this operation I think a join would do the job.
Something like this:

```
df1.join(df2, on='Movie_ID')
```

If you provide an example a can make the code more specific.

Comment: An example of the CSV files layout?

Comment: @MohamedRayyan, exactly. If you can also generate the correspondent dataframe would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pandas [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)
to reshape the data based on column values. Since not every user has rated every movie, the result possibly contain `NaN`s (which are cast into `float` type by Pandas). If you wish to convert the result to `int` you can append `.fillna(0).astype(int)` at the end of the `pivot` function.

*Sample df*

```py
    User_ID Movie_ID  Rating
0       131    38552       4
1       203    38552       4
2        50    38552       1
3       585    95894       1
4       138    94611       4
5       632    73111       0
6       328    95894       0
7       461    73111       0
8       924    73111       3
...
...
```

Pivot function

```py
df_new = df.pivot(index='User_ID', columns='Movie_ID', values='Rating').fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df_new)
```

```py
Movie_ID  193846  38552  73111  83641  93843  94611  95894
User_ID
7              0      0      2      0      0      0      0
43             0      0      0      0      0      0      0
50             0      1      0      0      0      0      0
85             0      0      0      0      0      0      0
131            0      4      0      0      0      0      0
138            0      0      0      0      0      4      0
145            0      0      4      0      0      0      0
156            0      0      4      0      0      0      0
195            0      0      3      0      0      0      0
203            0      4      0      0      0      0      0
209            0      0      0      0      0      0      0
```